# Using venv - VS Code debugging doesn't see all pip installed packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, pip

Running VS Code on Windows with Python 3.7.2 32bit with venv environments. I've searched and searched and either there's something I'm doing wrong, or VS Code won't do what I want it to do.

The VS Code debugger running under `"Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)"` doesn't find packages installed using `pip install` inside my `(env)`. In fact, it doesn't appear that the packages are being installed in the virtual environment at all.

Whenever I try to debug a single py file the debugger tells me it cannot find the package I installed using `pip`. I installed the packages inside the `venv (env)`, or so I thought. However, running `pip list` with the `(env)` active shows the same list as when it's deactivated.

I've noticed that running `pip install` while the `(env)` is active doesn't always result in the package being installed inside my environment. `pip list` will show it, but `pip show` shows it in Python's `appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages`.

I'm creating the environments using `python -m venv env` inside the vs code terminal (either python shell or git bash shell). It shows the `(env)` as active, so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I have not changed the launch.json config:
 `{
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
         }`

VS Code shows I'm using the correct venv interpreter:

`Python 3.7.2 32-bit ('env': venv)`

Running the script directly in the VS Code terminal `python script.py` works correctly every time.

Manually copying packages from:

`appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages`

to

`env\lib\site-packages`

allows the debugger to work without errors. This is great, and it's a workaround, but it appears the issue is more with my `venv` not actually acting like a `venv`.

I don't see any issue with venv on my linux machines, but they're mostly headless so I'm not running VS Code.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding:

```
"justmycode": false
```

in the debug configuration?
It defaults to true, and will only let you debug your own files.
Here my config:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    }
```

Comment: I had set "justMyCode" to true for a single configuration, and it was giving me an error that I hadn't had before about trying to find dist-packages in my virtual environment path. There was a site-packages, but no dist-package. Setting "justMyCode" to true made the issue go away. So while your answer may not be appreciated by some it may have helped me!

Answer (score 1):

It is strange but it worked for me!

Try to activate your virtual environment from terminal in vscode. then do not choose the venv environment from UI interpreter selector and just use your ordinary python interpreter. You shouldn't see the venv name in the bottom left of the vs code editor.

Then debug the code from Run > Start debugging and it now finds the packages!!!

Comment: But, this way you won't have your packages of the virtual environment, and will be using the default environment instead when debugging.

Comment: Actually the strange part was that it was able to detect my venv installed packages since I have activated the venv from the VS Code Terminal (not using GUI).

Answer (score 0):

Could be caused by the language server Jedi.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and enter "settings" and select "Open Settings (JSON)" with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

to open `settings.json` and add

```
    "python.jediEnabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi"
```

to **disable** it.

I know it seems counterintuitive, but after I did this, it found my packages of the selected python interpreter and didn't find them again when I uninstalled them.

Give it a shot, it's easy to undo if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

my current temp solution...on top of  python file add path to your venv python

#! ~/.venv/bin/python

I have a similar issue in VS Code, can run it from vevn> python /path/file.py but if I do it from VS Code Gui (even after selecting enterpreter venv in command pallet and confirm it in status bar at the bottom) it still say module is not found:(